# Why in Edmonds Karp or Ford Fulkerson Algorithm the time complexity of BFS or DFS respectively is O(E) rather than O(V+E)?

Tags: time-complexity, breadth-first-search, max-flow, ford-fulkerson, edmonds-karp

For these algorithmt the time complexity of BFS and DFS is O(E).

I have gone through a lot of websites and even the algorithm books, but never got the clear idea of why it is O(E). It just says its O(E) in flow graph as it consider only edges. What does this mean?

Comment: This would be a better fit on [Cs.se]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular okay, thanks.